# Setting different default values for DropDownLists from SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller which gives a `SelectList` to a View which then renders multiple `DropDownLists` for a `SelectList`. I now want the `DropDownLists` to have different Values to be selected by Default. Is there any way of doing this?

Edit: Oh and of course the values I want to be defaults are available from my Model e.g. `Model.Dj1_Id` etc.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditPartyInfo(int ID)
    {
        Party prty = db.Partys.Find(ID);
        ViewBag.People = new SelectList(db.People, "Id", "Name");
        return View(prty);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Musa.Models.Party

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPartyInfo", "Events", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!-- Some text input fields -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Dj1_Id">Dj 1</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownList("Dj1_Id", ViewBag.People as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control person-select", style = "width: 50%;" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Dj2_Id">Dj 2</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownList("Dj2_Id", ViewBag.People as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control person-select", style = "width: 50%;" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Dj3_Id">Dj 3</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownList("Dj3_Id", ViewBag.People as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control person-select", style = "width: 50%;" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Los geht's" />
}
```

I Actually ended up doing:

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditPartyInfo(int ID)
    {
        Party prty = db.Partys.Find(ID);
        ViewBag.People = db.People;
        return View(prty);
    }
```

View:

```
/*...*/
@Html.DropDownList("Dj1_Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.People, "Id", "Name", Model.Dj1_Id), String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control person-select", style = "width: 50%;" })
/*...*/
@Html.DropDownList("Dj2_Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.People, "Id", "Name", Model.Dj2_Id), String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control person-select", style = "width: 50%;" })
/*...*/
@Html.DropDownList("Dj3_Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.People, "Id", "Name", Model.Dj3_Id), String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control person-select", style = "width: 50%;" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try;

instead of

```
ViewBag.People as SelectList
```

this;

```
new SelectList(ViewBag.People, "Id", "Name", "Id value to select")
```

as second parameter of `Html.DropDownList`s

Answer (score 1):

SelectList has a constructor where you can pass in the selected object, so:

```
new SelectList(db.People, "Id", "Name", db.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == party.Dj1_Id)
```

I personally prefer using `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` like so:

```
ViewBag.People = db.People.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id, Selected = x.Id == party.Dj1_Id);
```

Either way should work.